# Unable to read a file and returns its result nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

Using [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module). And I'm unable to accomplish a thing wherein I'm want to modify the mtime of a file(`touch.txt`).

I tried using ..

> os.execute("touch /app/directory/touch.txt")

and this

> io.open('/app/directory/touch.txt','w').close()

But none of the above is working ..

Here how my nginx.conf looks like this ..

```
location / {
               auth_basic "Prohibited area";
               auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
               default_type 'text/plain';
               content_by_lua_block {
                  os.execute('/usr/bin/touch /app/directory/touch.txt')
                  local time = os.date("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
                  ngx.say('Hello,world! '.. time)
               }
                proxy_redirect  off;
}
```

I see the time returned i.e (`Hello,world! '.. time`) in browser correctly but the mtime of `touch.txt` remain still the same.

Any things over here .. that I need to take care of.

Comment: Perhaps nginx doesn't have the right to change that file.  You could have put some more effort in verifying the results of the "os.execute".

Comment: Oh shoot How can I do that ,, ?

Comment: Read and accept my answer, and sinneth no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    location /lua {
      content_by_lua_block {
        local res = os.execute('/usr/bin/touch /tmp/touch.txt')
        local time = os.date("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
        if res == 0 then
          ngx.header["Content-type"] = "text/plain"
          ngx.say('Hello,world! '.. time)
        else
          ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_NOT_FOUND
          ngx.header["Content-type"] = "text/plain"
          ngx.say('The world is doomed '.. time)
          ngx.say('because of  ' .. res)
        end
    }
```